# How to read multiple(more than 2) .txt files using python

Tags: python

I have 2 or more than .txt file contains

```
file1.txt 
India
File2.txt
US
```

I wanted to write output in third file as India US.
Please any one can tell me how to do it using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob
all_text_files = glob.glob('/path/to/dir', '*.txt')

with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as fh:
     for text_file in all_text_files:
         data = open(text_file, 'r')
         fh.write(data.read())
```

`glob.glob('*.txt')` returns ALL the `.txt` files in the current directory.
If you want to read only a few files, you can specify them in a list

```
all_text_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ....., 'filen.txt']
```

Comment: or all_text_files = glob.glob1('/pth/to/dir', '*.txt')

Answer (score 0):

```
source_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fh_out:
    for fname in source_files:
        with open(fname, 'r') as fh:
            fh_out.write(fh.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['file1.txt','file2.txt']

for file in files:
  with open(file,'r') as file_read:
    with open('file3.txt', 'w+') as file_put:
      file_put.write(file_read.read())
```